# mongodb - querying & projecting element value from nested array

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I have a nested arrays as below in one of my collections,

[image]

how to retrieve the value from specific sub array & i don't need any of the other fields in that document. 
I have tried using following query but it didn't get me the expected output,

query:

```
db.getCollection('my_collection').find({"_id":"08d4608a-e6c4-1bd8-80e6-8d1ac448c34b"},{"_id":0,"customProperties.0.1":1})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
db.getCollection.find({
    "someArray.someNestedArray.name": "value"
})
```

Comment: this is not that i'm expecting...I need find on "_id" with nested array in projection.